# Similar functionality as TreeView refresh() method

Tags: javafx-8

In JavaFX 8u60 there is a new method [`TreeView.refresh()`](http://download.java.net/jdk9/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html#refresh--).

It is very handy but for the my current version (8u45), I could't find any way to get the TreeView values to be refreshed when I update some items.

Can you propose some handy way in 8u45 which can help me to get the same result as the method `TreeView.refresh()`?

Comment: don't use refresh - that's an emergency exit for the extreme rare corner case when your data can't notify about its changes

Comment: Can you post a MVCE where the updated items don't get refreshed.

Comment: @kleopatra is there any other better alternative?

Comment: let your data fire appropriate notifications ... that's what they normally do in the fx universe anyway, no need to interfere